# Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "и" в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

При росте риска инвестиций инвестору могут предложить более высокую норму прибыли, однако риск потери инвестируемых денег, безусловно, увеличивается(,) и это закономерный процесс.

Answer (score 1):

При росте риска инвестиций инвестору могут предложить более высокую норму прибыли, **однако** риск потери инвестируемых денег, безусловно, увеличивается, и это закономерный процесс.

**Противительный союз  ОДНАКО** не является общим элементом, поэтому между предложениями 2 и 3 ставится запятая.

[Розенталь. § 30. Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133)

**Противительный союз**, после которого или перед которым находятся два соединенных союзом **и** простых предложения, общим элементом не является, поэтому запятая перед **и** ставится: *Ибрагим был бы очень рад избавиться, но ассамблея была дело должностное, и государь строго требовал присутствия своих приближённых* (П.).

Answer (score 0):

**(1) При росте риска инвестиций инвестору могут предложить более высокую норму прибыли, (2) однако риск потери инвестируемых денег, безусловно, увеличивается, (3) и это закономерный процесс.**

ССП состоящее из трех, разделенных запятыми.

Можно поставить тире, если вы считаете, что последнее предложение содержит  вывод из сказанного в двух первых:

**При росте риска инвестиций инвестору могут предложить более высокую норму прибыли, однако риск потери инвестируемых денег, безусловно, увеличивается – и это закономерный процесс.**

Я предложил два варианта, так как смысл предложения мне не совсем ясен, 
не могу уверенно сказать, что влючает в себя указанный "процесс".

Мне казалось, что существует еще и третий варинант: запятая может не ставиться, если считать, что "однако" по смыслу является общим для (2) и (3). Однако Arina указала: "Противительный союз, после которого или перед которым находятся два соединенных союзом и простых предложения, общим элементом не является, поэтому запятая перед "и" ставится". Надеюсь, это послужит хорошим уроком не только для меня.

Дополнение.

Все-таки вопрос о смысле этой фразы остается открытым.

"Рост риска инвестиций" и  "риск потери инвестируемых денег увеличивается" – разве это не одно и то же, сказанное разными словами?